# How to add an applet to XFCE systray?

Tags: xfce

I had Gmixer applet in systray but I was told to remove it and use pavucontrol (also an applet). Ok, I did, now I don't have any volume control in systray. When I go to systray preferences I can see a list of applets, but the ones that are already shown, not the programs I could add to systray.

So how to add an applet to systray? pavucontrol in my case.

**Update** my distro is openSUSE (13.2).

Comment: It depends on your distribution, for example I use Arch and for a systray volume control that integrates decently enough with pulseaudio I'm using pasystray-git from the aur. Maybe pasystray has also been adopted on other distros.

Comment: Right now I am using Linux Mint Mate Sarah.
I got pasystray to show up in notification area by adding it to startup applications.